# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsSocials is not a function

Tags: javascript, share

```html
<div id="share"></div>
```

I don't know why it shows Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsSocials is not a function for this code is correct already add jQuery and other files

```html
<script>
$("#share").jsSocials({
  shares: [
    "email",
    "twitter",
    "facebook",
    "googleplus",
    "linkedin",
    "pinterest",
    "stumbleupon",
    "whatsapp",
  ],
});
</script>
```

I already have `jQuery` installed.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError` or `Uncaught Error` ? Information from your post is confusing, please update with more details and if possible a code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

It means `$` is not `defined`. Usually `$` is a shortcut for `jQuery`. If you only need the selector you could probably also use [zepto.js](https://zeptojs.com/)

You need to include jQuery or Zeptin in your source.

Try with https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

Ex:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: already added jQuery

Comment: It looks it's not loaded in your environement, how did you install jQuery? Update the question with more details, and perhaps add a code sample

Comment: now it says  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsSocials is not a function

Comment: Sounds like jsSocials isn't installed properly then.